# Proving a sequence on homology is exact

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $0 \overset{}{\longrightarrow} K \overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} L \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} M \overset{}{\longrightarrow} 0$ be an exact sequence of chain complexes. Prove  that the sequence $$\dots \overset{}{\longrightarrow} H_{n+1}(M) \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow}H_n(K) \overset{\alpha_\sharp}{\longrightarrow} H_n(L) \overset{\beta_\sharp}{\longrightarrow} H_n(M) \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow}H_{n-1}(K) \overset{}{\longrightarrow} \dots$$ is exact at $H_n(L)$.

To show that this is exact at $H_n(L)$ one needs to show that $\ker (\beta_\sharp) = \text{Im}(\alpha_\sharp)$. First of all don't we usually use $f_\sharp$ for the chain maps and $f_\ast$ for the induced maps on homology? The notation in this case would be a bit faulty then.

So to show equality $\ker (\beta_\sharp) = \text{Im}(\alpha_\sharp)$, first consider $[c] \in  \text{Im}(\alpha_\sharp) \subset H_n(L)$. Now $$[c] = \alpha_\sharp([\sigma])$$ for some $[\sigma] \in H_n(K)$ and applying $\beta_\sharp$ we have $$\beta_\sharp([c])=\beta_\sharp(\alpha_\sharp([\sigma])) = [\beta(\alpha(\sigma))] = [0]$$ since the induced maps on homology are defined by $f_\sharp([\sigma]) \mapsto [f(\sigma)].$

The other direction is slightly trickier. If $[c] \in \ker(\beta_\sharp)$, then $[c]$ is a homology class in $H_n(L)$ such that $\beta_\sharp([c]) = 0$. This means that $[\beta(\sigma)]=0$ and so $\beta(\sigma)$ is a boundary i.e. $\beta(\sigma) = \partial(\tau)$ for some $\tau \in C_n(M)$.

I'm stuck at this point. What would be the ways to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "$f_*$" would make more sense.

To proceed, you need to use the exactness at $M$: $\tau$ is equal to $\beta(\tau ')$ for $\tau ' \in C_n(L).$ Now what about $\sigma - \partial\tau'$? Since $\beta$ and $\partial$ commute, it is in the genuine (chain-level) kernel of $\beta_\#,$ so we can use the exactness of the given sequence at $L$: $\sigma - \partial \tau' = \alpha (k).$ It's left to notice that $\sigma - \partial \tau'$, whose class we've shown to be in the image of $\alpha_\#$, defines the same homology class as $\sigma.$